VSCode only shows tiniest sliver of Jupyter Notebook metadata section in git diff view
When I have made changes to my Jupyter Notebook and go to source control in VSCode and click on the file name to view the diff, the metadata section appears as just a tiny sliver of the view and I cannot access it to read it. If I place my mouse in just the right spot I can scroll up and down in the sliver, but obviously I can't really tell what it says.

Has anyone encountered this glitch before and know a way to fix it? The only way around it I have found so far is clicking the Open Text Diff Editor button which isn't my favorite way to view changes.
I have restarted VSCode to no avail. I've collapsed and reopened the metadata section. I've moved my mouse around to see if I can find a handle to pull the window down somehow. I've thrown it on another monitor at a different resolution. I've unchecked and rechecked Show Metadata Differences from the three-dot, upper-right corner button of VSCode. I'm using the most up-to-date versions:

VSCode 1.9.0
Jupyter extension v2024.5.0

